# IOS How to get image from IPhone camera scene by programmatically without press shoot button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-capture

I am trying to get image from camera and send it to the server automatically.
So I want to know how to capture image from iphone camera scene without press shoot button.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202310/how-can-i-capture-an-image-from-ios-camera-without-user-interaction or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106486/how-to-save-photos-taken-using-avfoundation-to-photo-album

Comment: Thanks for answering.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106486/how-to-save-photos-taken-using-avfoundation-to-photo-album
it works. 
Thanks again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20934187/653513

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to save photos taken using AVFoundation to Photo Album?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106486/how-to-save-photos-taken-using-avfoundation-to-photo-album)
I use this code and solve problem.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112
AV Cam-iOS also can solve my problem.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it is possible. Capturing image using Camera interface will trigger `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` methods. The delegates are only called when you pick an image through camera shutter button/image cropper.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there any camera interface to implement the feature what i want?  I mean not using UIImagePickerController.

Comment: There are many libraries which may suit your requirement. However i recently made my own custom camera interface. you can check this blog with an excellent tutorial you can follow. [link] (http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/custom-ios-camera-replicates-system-camera-app). Once captured image using the shutter button, you can handle image the way you want. Good luck

Comment: @RajD It is possible. It can be achieved by AVCaptureSession . You are missleading OP

Comment: @vivek i thought some kind of action is necessary to trigger the delegate method